# C++/WinRT using co_await in main()

Tags: asynchronous, c++-winrt

In a `Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT)` project the entry point is just the standard `int main()` function.

How can I get started with asynchronous code then?

For example, I want to call a method

```cpp
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction WriteToFileAsync()
{
    // calls FileIO::WriteTextAsync etc
}
```

from `main`.

---

`co_await` cannot be used, i.e.

```cpp
int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
    
    co_await ::WriteToFileAsync();
}
```

yields the error

> `function "main" cannot be a coroutine`

---

Am I supposed to use

```cpp
int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
    
    ::WriteToFileAsync().get();
}
```

instead?

Is there a better way in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mandated by the C++ Standard, the `main()` function cannot be a [coroutine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines). A function is a coroutine if it uses the `co_await` operator or the `co_yield` and `co_return` keywords.

Consequently, you will have to wait for any coroutines called from the `main()` function to run to completion. C++/WinRT provides the extension functions `get()` and `wait_for()` for [`IAsyncAction`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.iasyncaction) (and family) to do that.

I'm not aware of anything *"better"*, though I also don't understand why calling `get()` were bad.